# Is it possible to automate/script MOK (Machine Owner Key) enrollment in RHEL 8 VMware machine?

Tags: bootloader, uefi, hardening

I am able to add MOK (Machine Owner Key) to my Linux VM by using mokutil command below with a root password: **mokutil -i /path/to mykey/*.der**
However, after a reboot, I have to enroll a Machine Owner Key manually by entering information in an interactive mode.
Is it possible to automate/script MOK (Machine Owner Key) enrollment in RHEL 8 VMware machine ? Can anyone help me with that ?

I manually enrolled the machine with MOK. But I would like to know a way to automate/script all this MOK (Machine Owner Key) enrollment process.